# Call pushnotification after 24 hours php

Tags: php, push-notification, cron

I am new to stack overflow. 
My question : I have one question for calling push notification. I have stored start time and end time in db. I want to call push notification when current server time = end time.

Can anyone give me a head start for this?

Thanks in advance,
Kinjal Joshi

Comment: You've tagged this as `cron` so it sounds like you know roughly which direction to head. Where have you got to so far?

Comment: @iainn Thanks for your reply.  yes, I have some rough idea that it might be possible with cron. But I am not sure how to do it.